# How to render x items in xamarin without scroll

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Ok, this is a little strange, but I need to take a screenshot of a list of items in Xamarin. The problem is that I'm using a `ListView` and it only renders about 5 items. I need to render *all* elements in the list. I don't care if it's smaller on-screen; I just want to take a screenshot of the view and be able to share it.

This is my .xaml:

```
<BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="0.5" Color="Gray"/>
    <controls:CustomListView x:Name="list"
            ItemsSource="{Binding List}"  
            HeightRequest="1000" VerticalOptions="Fill"
            HasUnevenRows="True">
        <x:Arguments>
            <ListViewCachingStrategy>RecycleElement</ListViewCachingStrategy>
        </x:Arguments>  
        <controls:CustomListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <cell:ItemViewCell></cell:ItemViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:CustomListView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:CustomListView>
<BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="0.5" Color="Gray"/>
```

This is for Android.

Comment: There are ways to "render" a complete view into an image (or pdf) and they are *different* per OS but there is nothing in Xamarin.Forms that supports that as a default feature. These rendering methods are limited via memory when dealing with a "image snapshot" as just how many elements are in the list view, instancing all those ViewModels, creating each view element, etc... If number of items of fairly limited you could create a custom page/view and play with scaling of the view in order to make all the elements visible at one time and take an API-based screen cap of it assuming it is readable

Comment: Thanks, I had to create pdf, it is not possible to "overlap" the boundaries of the screen, At least no with a List, I went the pdf way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create pdf, it is not possible to "overlap" the boundaries of the screen, At least no with a List, I went the pdf way

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind you something like this on the OnAppearing method

```
list.HeightRequested = list.ItemSource.Count * list.RowHeight;
```

you can also try to do the same thing on the CustomList's OnPropertyChanged where propertyName is ItemSource whatever feels best for you